# MVC3 parameter use by layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, navigation

I have a custom section that uses a custom layout. This section is dynamic and all the actions will receieve a YEAR parameter. I don't want setup navigation via section from inside the views. What would be the best way to get this parameter in a navigation action utilized by the layout? If the year is in the URL as ?year=2012 then I can get it via query string. My problem is that this may be in there as controller/action/2012. How can I get the year now in navigation action?

Comment: I can use view bag to hold the year from inside my action, but want to know/learn if I this can be handled better.

Answer (score 0):

controller/action?year=2012 and controller/action/2012 are basically same if you have defined your route as

```
{controller}/{action}/{year}
```

In the action

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(int year)
    {
     :
     :
     :
    }
}
```

If you have defined above route along with the default route ( {controller}/{action}/{id} )

Both the url MyController/MyAction?year=2012 and MyController/MyAction/2012 will be treated equally.

Comment: That is correct... the layout will be using action BuildNav to dynamically build the nav for the year. If the route is being used then how can I get the year in BuildNav action. I don't want to implement this action via section in my MyAction view.

Comment: I didnt understand what exactly you want to achieve.Can you please explain some more detail

Comment: I want to access the year in BuildNav action. It is available to me in MyAction action as specified in your example also.

Comment: OK, So where ever you are generating the link you can specify like, @Html.Action("BuildNav","YourController",new{@year=2012}), it will generate the link like YourController/BuildNav/2012. Now the request will come to BuildNav action.